# What is the difference between RX and TX jobs?

Tags: printer

I have an office printer that I fax, print, and scan with. When I go into the logs to get a fax or scan confirmation, I notice they are under **TX Job Logs**. But there's also a menu for **RX Job Logs**.

What's the difference between the two?

I've googled this but I get a bunch of results that don't seem to have anything to do with printers.

Comment: RX and TX is Recieve Transaction and Transmite Transaction.  As for the specific meaning for your printer the manual should have the answer.

Comment: @Ramhound Oh boy I'm dumb. That's pretty obvious XD I checked the manual, but couldn't find anything, but it probably wasn't there because that's a no brainer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

probably "TX Job Logs" stands for "Transmit Job Logs" (Send faxes) and "RX Job Logs" for "Receive Job Logs" (Received faxes).